# Azure devops repo can not integrate with codeanywhere

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos, codeanywhere

i have export ssh public key from codeanywhere and import to azure devops, but when to use the git clone url from azure repo to import to codeanywhere, there will be an error from codeanywhere as below:

"*Request createProjectFromGit failed with message: Cloning into 'repo002'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.*"

The same method, i can able to launch online ide for github, gitlab, and bitbucker repo. but only azure repo i can not make it. Or azure repo will be a close box and can not access to another third party ide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow below steps to use the git clone url from azure repo to import to codeanywhere：

1   copy codeanywhere Public SSH key and import to azure devops . This key can authorize Codeanywhere to access your resource in azure repo.

[image: add SSH]

2 use git clone command to get the repo from azure devops.
[image: git clone in codeanywhere]

After running the git clone command, you can clone the repo from Azure DevOps successfully. And it shows that Azure DevOps can integrate with codeanywhere.

3   if you failed to clone the repo in codeanywhere, check  below conditions:

(1) Manually record the SSH key by running:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa ssh.dev.azure.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

(2) Check if your Public SSH key set correctly in Azure DevOps.

(3) Check if you set any Repositories policies and Branch Policies that  could prevent codeanywhere  from having access to Azure Repository.

(4) Check you Repository name

(5) Check your Application Connection Policies and make  sure to enable ‘’SSH authentication’’
[image: enable SSH]

Comment: i was figured it out that org need to be public. thank you in advance